# Javascript prototype function undefined when constructor call in parentheses

Tags: javascript

Why does

```js
function Example() {
  this.go();
}
Example.prototype.go = function() {
    console.log("going");
  }
  (new Example());
```

bark at me that this.go is not a function whereas

```js
function Example() {
  this.go();
}
Example.prototype.go = function() {
  console.log("going");
}
new Example();
```

is logging correctly as expected?

Execution environment is node v10.4.1 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

Comment: As has been pointed out, it's a missing `;`,  May I advice you use an editor with built in linting, as things like this get picked up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are depending on [ASI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) and it isn't working the way you expect.

In the first example, the `()` are turning the function expression you are trying to assign to `Example.prototype.go` into an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

Consequently, the order of events is:

1. `Example` is defined
2. `new Example()` is evaluated
3. The result is passed as an argument in a call to the anonymous function
4. The return value of that function (`undefined`) is assigned to `Example.prototype.go`

… except it errors at step 2 because `go` isn't defined at that point.

End each statement with an explicit semi-colon to avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're relying on Automatic Semicolon Insertion (ASI) (perhaps unintentionally), but also starting a line with a `(`. If you correctly terminate the assignment with a `;`, the problem goes away:

```js
function Example() {
  this.go();
}
Example.prototype.go = function() {
    console.log("going");
}; // <==== ; here
(new Example());
```

The problem is that **without** the `;`, the `()` expression following the assignment combines with the `function() { }` expression in front of it in a syntactically- (but not logically-) valid way: It *calls* the function, passing in the result of `new Example`. So ASI doesn't kick in.

If you aren't intentionally relying on ASI, just note that assignment expressions need to be terminated with `;`s.

If you are intentionally relying on ASI, you must start lines that have a leading `(` or `[` with a proactive `;` for this very reason. So in your case:

```
    function Example() {
      this.go();
    }
    Example.prototype.go = function() {
        console.log("going");
    }
    ;(new Example());
//  ^----
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you forgot a semicolon after the function *expression* assigned to `.go`:

```
Example.prototype.go = function() {
  console.log("going");
} // <--- no semicolon!
(new Example());
```

The following line *beings with opening parentheses* - thus, the interpreter thinks you're *immediately* calling the aforementioned function:

```
Example.prototype.go = function() {
  console.log("going");
}(new Example());
```

This is happening *before* `Example.prototype.go` has been assigned to - the interpreter is trying to evaluate the right-hand side of the expression to a value before assigning the result to `Example.prototype.go`. But you're calling `new Example()` *before* `Example.prototype.go` is populated; thus, `this.go` is `undefined`.

Just put a semicolon after the `}` instead:

```
Example.prototype.go = function() {
  console.log("going");
};
(new Example());
```